# Google AJAX API, jQuery & google.load() vs $(function() {})

Tags: jquery, google-ajax-api

when i use google.load() to load jquery, what do i use in place of

```
$(function() {
 ... 
});
```

is ...

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
 ...
});
```

the same thing? this may be too slow if i am loading alot with google.load()?

then will

```
google.load("jquery", "1.3.2", {callback: docLoaded()});
```

run AFTER the whole document is loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here :
[Google Ajax Apis Playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=libraries#jquery)

The way they do it is like this :

```
google.load("jquery", "1");

function OnLoad(){
  // some Jquery instructions
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be safe using `$(function)` still, since it will wait for google to load jQuery, it is after all a part of the document. Or am I wrong here?

I always use local versions anyway..Just feels safer, you know (:

**edit:** Just tested it, and it worked, just using the regular `$(function)`

Comment: err i did google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
google.load("maps", "2");
$(function () {
    alert("Hello");
}); and nth happened ...

Comment: Just would like to add, that $(function() {}) is the equivalent of $.ready() and is triggers before $.load() ! http://api.jquery.com/ready/ The difference is that for ready the DOM is built, but images, css artifacts might still not be all loaded.